# SOQL exclude records with blank values on Multi-select picklist fields

Tags: soql, picklist

I have field `Application_type__c` on lead object which is multiselect picklist.
I want to exclude records where picklist value is No application' or 'Global Markets or Blank.

My query is

```
Select Id, Name,Application_type__c , Lead_Age_Days__c from Lead 
                                where isConverted = false
                                and (
                                    (LeadSource = 'Client-Portal-Lead' and Client_Portal_Stage__c = 'Page2 Completed') 
                                    or (LeadSource = 'Client-Portal-Lead-Ar' and Client_Portal_Stage__c = 'Page2 Completed') 
                                    or (LeadSource = 'Manual entry' and Client_Portal_Stage__c = null)
                                    ) 
                                and Entity__c = 'Abu Dhabi' 
                                and CST_Owner__c = null 
                                and Application_type__c excludes ('No application','Global Markets') 
                                ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
```

I get required result + Record where this field is blank or NULL.

If I change

`Application_type__c excludes ('No application','Global Markets')`     to

```
Application_type__c excludes ('No application','Global Markets','')
```

It gives results with No application as well.

How can I exclude record where this field is NULL or blank

Comment: Have you tried using "Application_type__c != 'No application' AND Application_type__c != 'Global Markets'" to see if the result is still the same?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira , that was the first thing i tried, it will not work in case of multi select picklist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Application_type__c` is apparently a multi-select picklist which are also of Type string, it would seem you'd want to specify

```
Application_type__c excludes ('No application','Global Markets') AND !Application_type__c.isEmpty()
```

`string.isEmpty()` tests for both empty strings and strings with a value of `null`.

Comment: Thank you @crmprogdev. Working fine with your solution : 

Select Id, Name,Application_type__c , Lead_Age_Days__c from Lead 
where isConverted = false
and (
 (LeadSource = 'Client-Portal-Lead' and Client_Portal_Stage__c = 'Page2 Completed') 
 or (LeadSource = 'Client-Portal-Lead-Ar' and Client_Portal_Stage__c = 'Page2 Completed') 
 or (LeadSource = 'Manual entry' and Client_Portal_Stage__c = null)
 ) 
and Entity__c = 'Abu Dhabi' 
and CST_Owner__c = null 
and Application_type__c excludes ('No application','Global Markets') 
and Application_type__c !='' 
ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC