# SOQL Count of non-blank multi-select fields

Tags: soql, multi-select, where

I'm trying to find out how many people answered a multi-select question in a survey.  For this count I do not need to know what they picked, simply that they picked something (or didn't not pick anything??)

All my efforts return error: 'Field multi__c does not support aggregate operator COUNT'

Maybe I should create a text formula field that pulls the contents of the multi-select and count the nonblank text field?

Any other options?

(I'm setting this up in Declarative Lookup Rollups app, don't know if it is adding an extra limitation, I can't find reference anywhere to this null issue)

FYI I've tried 
WHERE field !=''
WHERE field != NULL
WHERE Field EXCLUDES (NULL)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this was asked before [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98494/soql-exclude-records-with-blank-values-on-multi-select-picklist-fields). Can you try this?

```
 multi__c excludes ('valueA','valueB') AND
 multi__c.isEmpty()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to do this in Declarative Lookup Rollups app, since it is on the Campaign rolling up a custom object.  I don't want to hard-code values into the rollup, just count non-blank fields.  Tried the multi__c.isEmpty(), but it also returns; error is 'unexpected token: ')''  So I don't know if this is a DLR limitation or a syntax issue.